# Non dairy types of milk taste raw seeds/nuts, how to get rid of it?

Tags: seeds, dairy-free

I usually use sunflower seeds to make homemade non dairy milk and it has a taste of raw seeds and homemade soy milk has the same issues. Well, it's an issue for me.

Comment: I've had this problem with homemade cashew milk also

Comment: I'd guess that you want to heat it up to destroy that flavor. See this link: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25379/is-it-possible-to-make-soymilk-without-a-beany-taste.

Comment: @Batman I thought of that too but with nuts and seeds it may destroy the milk, at least this is what I think. I tried roasting them slightly before soaking and blending and it didn't become milky. I'll give it a try with a ready made milk.

Comment: With a commercial milk, you might get some different behavior due to additives and different processing than you do at home.